# Database design with types and subtypes

Tags: mysql, database-design, subtype

I am trying to design a database that has supertype/subtypes. I have the following users:
- basic user
- business user
- administrator (super user).

All three users share a common table (users) where fields like name, email, password, etc are stored. However, the business users have a separate table (business) where the business fields like business_name, business_license, business_email, etc are stored. My problem is that my business users are themselves split into 5 or more categories.
My business users are split like this:

1. painters
2. vehicle detailers
3. lot attendants
4. service technicians:

   1. engine technicians
   2. transmission technicians
   3. computer technicians
   4. electrical technicians
5. sales representatives

   1. physical location sales representative
   2. internet sales representative
   3. sales manager

One thing to mention is that I want to have all of these business users stored into some table so adding and removing of positions to be easily made without messing to much on the application level.

I currently designed this database but I not really happy with it. Is there a better approach?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your design is decent. I like it. Put some data in it and write some queries. You can normalize it a little more if you so desire. Here's the SQLFiddle you can play with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0711/3 and below are the statements.

**Users and types**

```
create table usertypes (id int, typename varchar(100));
insert into usertypes values (1,'Basic'), (2, 'Business'), (3, 'Super');

create table users (
  id int, 
  email varchar(100), usertype int, fullname varchar(100)
);
insert into users values 
(1, 'a@b.com', 1, 'Tom Basic'),
(2, 'b@c.com', 2, 'Bill Business'),
(3, 'c@d.com', 3, 'Charlie Super');

-- USERS will have SUBTYPES in this many to many table. This will allow
-- a user to be a part of multiple subtypes if you please. You can control
-- that. If userid is primary key, one user can be of only one subtype
-- If userid and usertype make up a composite primary key, a user can be
-- of multiple types
create table userstypes (userid int, usertype int);
insert into userstypes values (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);
```

**Businesses and users**

```
create table businesses (
  id int,
  doing_business_as varchar(100), phone varchar(30)
);
insert into businesses values (1, 'Microsoft', '111-222-3333');
insert into businesses values (2, 'Toms Hardware', '111-222-3333');

-- Same as user types
-- DANGER: if you mark a user to be of type 'Basic', nothing stops that
-- user to have a business. You can use a trigger to allow only business
-- user to have an entry here
create table usersbusinesses (userid int, businessid int);
insert into usersbusinesses values (1,2), (2, 1);
```

**Business subtypes**

```
create table businesstypes (id int, businesstypename varchar(100));
insert into businesstypes values (1, 'Software'), (2, 'Hardware');

create table businessestypes (businessid int, businesstypes int);
insert into businessestypes values (1, 1), (2, 2);

-- DANGER: This design allows only 1 level of subtype. If a business
-- has a subtype, and that subtype has a sub-subtype and so on, this
-- design will not scale. Hierarchical design will scale but may also 
-- need performance tuning
create table businesssubtypes (id int, businesssubtypename varchar(100));
insert into businesssubtypes values (1, 'Garden Tools'), (2, 'Heavy Machine');

create table businesstypes_subtypes (businessid int, businesssubtypeid int);
insert into businesstypes_subtypes values (2,2);
```

Depending on your application needs, I would recommend doing appropriate denormalization. For really small, very low-effort projects I would make a flat structure in one table itself.